# Auto-update Chrome Extension Counter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to develop Chrome Extensions.

I have a [counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfIPW.png).

and this is my code for it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
   i++;
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: i.toString() } );
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "#000"})

  }, 1000);

})
```

and the counter works only whan I click that icon, how do I make him to update always, not only when I click on it.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/aFBDStyX) is my manifest.json file

Thanks

Comment: It works for me. Where does the code reside in your extension?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `background.js`

```
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:String(i)});
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working variant where recursion is used instead of `SetInterval()` function.

Reference [**YouTube Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_qE1iAmjFg#t=7m46s)

#### Changes made to `manifest.json` file

Eliminated `"persistent" : true` because by [default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) they are given a value `true`.

#### Code added  to `weather.js`

I used recursion instead of `Setinterval()`, Some intresting differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

```
//Counter Initialized to Zero
var i = 0;
(function updateCounter() {
    //Counter Incremented
    i++;
    //Counter is set to Badge
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: i.toString()
    });
    //Used timeout with same interval
    setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000);
})();
//Badge Background color is set to black
$(document).ready(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
        color: "#000"
    })
})
```